# How to efficiently get the row indicies of a subquery or joined table using row_number()

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-execution-plan, row-number

I have a table of 'games' where some of those games (but not all) are grouped into 'campaigns' by a campaign ID.

I am trying to write an SQL query which will get a dataset containing various information about the games, but in particular: if a given game is part of a campaign how many games are in that campaign in total (I have this working) and the index of that game within the campaign (e.g. the earliest game in a campaign is index '1', the next is '2' and so on).

I have achieved this, but the execution plan looks terrible and the obvious way to fix that doesn't work, but I get ahead of myself.

Here is the working query, with some extraneous stuff removed:

```
        g1.`id` AS `game_id`,
        (SELECT
            COUNT(*)
            FROM `games` g3
            WHERE g3.`campaign` = g1.`campaign`
        ) AS `campaign_length`,
        ca2.`ri` AS `campaign_index`,
        ca1.`id` AS `campaign_id`, ca1.`name` AS `campaign_name`
    FROM `games` g1
    LEFT JOIN `campaigns` ca1 ON ca1.`id` = g1.`campaign`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            g4.`id` AS `id`,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY g4.`campaign`
                ORDER BY g4.`start` ASC) AS `ri`
            FROM `games` g4
        ) AS ca2 ON ca2.`id` = g1.`id`
    WHERE g1.`end` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    AND g1.`gamemaster` = 25
    ORDER BY g1.`start` ASC
    ;
```

The problem with this version is that for table g4 the execution plan lists a full table scan - which is fine at the moment as there's only a few hundred records, but long term will be terrible for performance, especially as this query (or ones very similar to it) will be executed on many different pages of my website. I believe this is happening because the ROW_NUMBER() function needs to number all the rows before the LEFT JOIN's ON statement can filter them down to the ones I actually need.

The obvious solution, which I have tried to no avail, is to add
`` WHERE g4.`campaign` = g1.`campaign` `` after `` FROM `games` g4 ``;
that way ROW_NUMBER() would only need to number those records that have a chance of being returned in the dataset. However this does not work because `` g1.`campaign` `` is not in scope.

I can do `` WHERE g4.`campaign` IS NOT NULL `` which at least gets the execution plan down to a Index Conditional instead of a full table scan, but it will still not scale nicely as the number of games in campaigns grows with time.

I know that my "obvious solution" won't work because of the scope problem, but does anyone have a suggestion for how I can achieve what I'm trying to do without a terrible execution plan?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.28

Comment: Am I correct in that each game associates with zero or one campaign? But never two or more campaigns?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: And that each game in a campaign can have a different GM?  Thus the GM's games may include campaign_index 1 and 3, but skip 2?  And that you need to skip #2 in that sequence in those circumstances?

Comment: Yes, that is a potential possibility. Also there will be versions of this query which do not select by gamemaster, only end time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, the `campaign_index` *must* be calculated *before* the `WHERE` clause is applied.  This means that calculation of the `campaign_index` will *always* require a full table scan, as the `WHERE` clause ***can't*** reduce the rows being computed over.

You can, however, use windowed functions rather than a self join and correlated sub-query...

```
WITH
  games AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY `campaign`
      )
        AS `campaign_length`,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY `campaign`
            ORDER BY `start`
      )
        AS `campaign_index`
    FROM
        games
)
SELECT
    games.*,
    campaigns.`name`   AS `campaign_name`
FROM
  games
LEFT JOIN
  campaigns
    ON campaigns.`id` = games.`campaign`
WHERE
      games.`end`        > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  AND games.`gamemaster` = 25
ORDER BY
  games.`start`
;
```

Comment: That is a pity. I really need to avoid that full table scan, for future scalability. Your answer implies that, if a campaign always has the same gamemaster, then some optimisation might be possible? Also thank you for pointing out the WITH clause, it is not a feature of SQL I was previously familiar with :)

Comment: @alarmsiren - If you filtered the above query by `campaign`, then the optimiser would see that processing other campaigns wouldn't change the results at all *(because it's in the `PARTITION BY`)*, thus it can chose to only process that single campaign's data *(assuming appropriate indexes, etc)*.  Consequently, if you added GM to the `PARTITION BY`, the optimiser would be able to process only the data for that GM, avoiding a full scan of all the data.  As it stands, there is no way to calculate the `campaign_length` or `campaign_index` without processing all the rows.

Comment: The alternative is to have triggers or other business logic that calculates and persists these values every time you add new records to the database.  *(Instead of calculating them at report time, calculate them at insert time.)*

Answer (score 0):

Copy the table into a new table with a fresh `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.  This will quickly add row numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE new_list (
    row_num INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    INDEX(row_num) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
  SELECT ... FROM ...
      ORDER BY ...   -- this will do the sorting before numbering
```